# Two divs on horizontal line – left and right aligned

Tags: html, inline

I need top header with two divs inline – left and right aligned. Please review code. Is this correct? Where do I need to add div class="clearfix"

```
<div class="container">
<div class="columns">
       <div id="div-left">
          Left aligned text
        </div>

        <div id="div-right">
          Right aligned text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#div-left {
  float:left;
  display:inline
}

#div-right {
  float:right;
  display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap two divs in a containing div, and give the inner divs float:left and float:right, and perhaps some width if you wish :)

```
<div>
  <div style="float:right">To the right</div>
  <div style="float:left">To the left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. That is not necessary. You will see that this works if you try it.

Comment: And can I use it without width:50%? I have responsive design - so they have to shrink in mobile view.

Comment: Thanks Maritim for your fast reply. I appreciate it. It seems that this code works. How can I set different font size for text in these divs from the rest of body – in CSS?

Comment: You're most welcome :) Font can be set with for instance font-family:Tahoma in the style-attribute. Although I do recommend putting all CSS rules in a separate stylesheet.